# Is there any library out there that supports p2p live chat in react-native?

Tags: react-native, hybrid-mobile-app, livechat

Please I'm building an app with react native and I need to integrate a p2p live chat in it. Is there any library out there that can do it ?

I haven't really tried anything, SDKs like Chatwoot are only users to support. But i want a situation where users can chat with users also

Comment: I havent tried it myself, but I ran across this article that has an example https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/peer-to-peer-chat-app-using-webrtc-and-react-native-6c15759f92ec

Comment: alright, thanks a lot, I'll check it out.